# How to remove the ASCII nul at the end of clipr::wirte_clip?

Tags: r, newline, clipboard

I love clipr::write_clip but I've noticed every time I write something to the clipboard with it, there is always a newline following it. Here's some sample code:

```
install.packages("clipr")
library(clipr)

text = "Hello world"
clipr::write_clip(text)
result = "Hello world
"
```

As you can see, when I paste the result into a set of quotation marks there is a pesky newline. Ideally when I paste the result into a set of quotes it would look like this:

```
result = "Hello world"
```

I've dug through the documentation at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clipr/versions/0.8.0/topics/write_clip and tried different settings for breaks and eos, but so far no luck. The description of eos says "The terminator to be written after each string, followed by an ASCII nul." and I think the ASCII nul is causing my problem here, does anyone know a way to get rid of it?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the result of `clipr::read_clip()`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to replicate, because:

```r
text = "Hello world"
clipr::write_clip(text, allow_non_interactive = TRUE)

clipr::read_clip(allow_non_interactive = TRUE)
#> [1] "Hello world"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Please note, `allow_non_interactive = TRUE` is just for reprex to be able to execute in background, it doesn't influence the results.

Comment: I'm not sure why the line break isn't there in read_clip, I assure you it is easy to replicate if you run the provided code and paste the result though

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using utils::writeClipboard instead

```
install.packages("utils")
library(utils)

text <- "Hello world"
utils::writeClipboard(str = charToRaw(paste0(text, " ")), format = 1)
"Hello world"
```

As you can see, pasting into a set of quotes after that call has no line break. This could probably also work with clipr:write_clip but it didn't seem to like being passed charToRaw so I just switched to utils::writeClipboard.
Thanks for the help all!